# Python: Merging and editing

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
year = 2014
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of_2014'
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
movieList = soup.findAll('table',{'class','wikitable'})
for list in movieList:
        rows = list.findAll('tr')
        for row in rows[:2]:
            #print row
            cells = row.findAll('td')
            i = len(cells)
            releaseDate = unicode(cells[i-5].find(text=True))
            month = unicode(cells[i-6].findAll(text=True))
            month = str(month)
            month = ''.join(str(item.strip()) for item in month)
            print "month: ",month
```

which prints
month:  [u'A',u'\nP',u'\nR']

i want to store this as a date 4 April 2014.
How can i first make the month as APR or April and then store it as a date?

Comment: Your last 2 lines don't make any sense.  Please post valid code

Comment: It's not just the last two lines...the `join` results in something else, as well...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> month = [u'A', u'\nP', u'\nR']
>>> ''.join(item.strip() for item in month)
u'APR'
```

You could use a dictionary like `{"JAN": "January", "FEB": "February", ...}` to then fetch the relevant month name for each abbreviation.

Comment: list comprehension is to be used within the join

Comment: Yes, it's a bit more efficient, though probably not relevant here.

Comment: @Tim, month is unicode how to do it now or should i do something in the begining?

Comment: I thought it was a typo and that's why I pointed it out. Turns out Python takes it as a generator and iterate without any problem.. Sweet. One more thing I learned today :-)

Comment: @Ankit: You could use `''.join(str(item.strip()) for item in month)` if you only expect ASCII letters in your month names.

Comment: @TimPietzcker month = ''.join(str(item.strip()) for item in month) still results in 
month =   [u'A',u'\nP',u'\nR']

Comment: @Ankit: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of doing

```
month = unicode(cells[i-6].findAll(text=True))
```

i did

```
month = cells[i-6]
month = [ele.get_text().strip() for ele in month]
month = ''.join(month)
```

which gives `month = u'A\nP\nR'`

now map it using

```
monthdict = {'A\nP\nR' : 'April'}
```